# java checkstyle equivalent for NOLINT

Tags: java, c++, coding-style, checkstyle

In C++ with cpplint.py, you can mute the stylechecker for a  via the `// NOLINT` phrase:

```
// Some C++ code that conflicts the styleguidelines:
void funtionWithNonConstReferenceArgument(int& A);  // NOLINT
```

Then the stylechecker will just ignore this line. Is there an equivalent for Java's checkstyle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Well, it's not exactly equivalent, since it's two comments around the code.

```
//CHECKSTYLE:OFF
/* your unstylish code */
//CHECKSTYLE:ON
```